# Problems with doubles in c

Tags: c, double, trigonometry

I made this code in class to practice recursion. It is a `sin` and `cos` calculator using *sin* and *cos* definition. This code prints an exemple of the correct `sin` and `cos` from the `<math.h>` library and the *sin* and *cos* from the calculator between 0 and 360 degrees. I think, There is a mistake and some results give me `#IND0`. Anyone know where the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define TOL 0.001

double my_sin(double num);
double my_cos(double num);

double a_radians(double num)
{
    return num * M_PI / 180;
}

double my_sin(double num)
{
    if (fabs(num) < TOL) {
        num = 1.0;
        return num;
    } else {
        num = 2.0 * (my_sin(num / 2.0)) * (my_cos(num / 2.0));
        return num;
    }
}

double my_cos(double num)
{
    if (fabs(num) < TOL) {
        num = 1.0;
        return num;
    } else {
        num = ((my_cos(num / 2.0)) * (my_cos(num / 2.0))) -
              ((my_sin(num / 2.0)) * (my_sin(num / 2.0)));
        return num;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int graus;
    double radians, cos_r, sin_r;

    graus = 0;

    while (graus <= 360) {
        printf("%d graus", graus);

        radians = a_radians(graus);
        printf("\n%f radiants", radians);

        sin_r = radians;
        sin_r = my_sin(sin_r);
        cos_r = radians;
        cos_r = my_cos(cos_r);

        printf("\nEl sin es %f", sin(radians));
        printf("\nEl sin de mysin es %.5f", sin_r);
        printf("\nEl cos es %f", cos(radians));
        printf("\nEl cos de mycos es %.5f\n\n", cos_r);

        graus = graus + 45;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to do a `sin` and `cos` calculator and it doesn't work.

Comment: The way this program flies off to wild results, even when setting a large value for `TOL`, is a strong indication that your claim _"there is no mistake"_ is itself a mistake.

Comment: There is no mistake but it isn't working :)

Comment: The problem isn't with doubles as the title suggests, but with somewhere else.

Comment: `my_sin(0.0)==1.0` is definitely a mathematical mistake.

Comment: regarding: `return num * M_PI / 180;`   Tihs is trying to calculate a 'double' but performing a integer divide .suggest changing '180' to '180.0'so so the calculation  produces a double result rather than a (rounded down) integer result

Comment: @user3629249 why? There is no integer division in `num * M_PI / 180`.  `num` and `M_PI` are `double`s  and a `doube` divided by an `int` yields a `double`. `180` is implicitly promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 7):

When the absolute value of the angle `num` is near to zero, the value of `sin(num)` can be approximated by `num`, not `1.0`.

```c
double my_sin (double num)
{
    if (fabs(num)<TOL){
        // remove this line
        // num=1.0;
        return num;
    }
    else{
        num=2.0*(my_sin(num/2.0))*(my_cos(num/2.0));
        return num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75789324/2410359) identification of OP's key problem, some other improvements

**Avoid redundant calls**

```
    //num = ((my_cos(num / 2.0)) * (my_cos(num / 2.0))) -
    //      ((my_sin(num / 2.0)) * (my_sin(num / 2.0)));
    double c = my_cos(num / 2.0);
    double s = my_sin(num / 2.0);
    num = c*c - s*s;
```

**Large angles**

When `|graus|` is much  larger than 360, the convergence is increasingly slow and incurs more accumulated error.

Reduce by a "mod" 360.0.

```
double a_radians(double num)
{
    num = fmod(num, 360.0);  // or the like
    return num * M_PI / 180;
}
```